# How to construct nilpotent of order $3$

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

Let $A = \pmatrix {a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}}$

Let $A \neq 0$ then construct a nilpotent matrix such that (1) $A^2 = 0$
(2) $A^2 \neq 0$ and $A^3 = 0$
Also find linearly independent eigen vectors in each case.

I have tried by multiplying matrix $A$ to itself and equated each element of $A^2$ to $0$, it becomes very tedious. Please help me.

Comment: Consider strictly upper-triangular matrices where all elements on or below the main diagonal are zero.

Comment: Case (1) $A^3 = 0, A^2 \neq 0, A = \pmatrix {0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_{21} & 0 & 0 \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & 0}$ 
or $A = \pmatrix {0 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 0 & 0 & a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$ , case (2),$A^2 = 0 , , A = \pmatrix {0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_{31} & 0 & 0}$ 
or $A = \pmatrix {0 & 0 & a_{13} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$. Thanks for hint.

Comment: Having solved this problem, you may want to read about [Grassmann numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number).